# Threading in a django app

Tags: python, django, multithreading

I'm trying to create what I call a scrobbler. The task is to read a Delicious user from a queue, fetch all of their bookmarks and put them in the bookmarks queue. Then something should go through that queue, do some parsing and then store the data in a database.

This obviously calls for threading because most of the time is spent waiting for Delicious to respond and then for bookmarked websites to respond and be passed through some API's and it would be silly for everything to wait for that.

However I am having trouble with threading and keep getting strange errors like database tables not being defined. Any help is appreciated :)

Here's the relevant code:

```
# relevant model #
class Bookmark(models.Model):
 account = models.ForeignKey( Delicious )
 url = models.CharField( max_length=4096 )
 tags = models.TextField()
 hash = models.CharField( max_length=32 )
 meta = models.CharField( max_length=32 )

# bookmark queue reading #
def scrobble_bookmark(account):
 try:
  bookmark = Bookmark.objects.all()[0]
 except Bookmark.DoesNotExist:
  return False

 bookmark.delete()

 tags = bookmark.tags.split(' ')
 user = bookmark.account.user

 for concept in Concepts.extract( bookmark.url ):
  for tag in tags:
   Concepts.relate( user, concept['name'], tag )

 return True

def scrobble_bookmarks(account):
 semaphore = Semaphore(10)
 for i in xrange(Bookmark.objects.count()):
  thread = Bookmark_scrobble(account, semaphore)
  thread.start()

class Bookmark_scrobble(Thread):
 def __init__(self, account, semaphore):
  Thread.__init__(self)
  self.account = account
  self.semaphore = semaphore

 def run(self):
  self.semaphore.acquire()
  try:
   scrobble_bookmark(self.account)
  finally:
   self.semaphore.release()
```

This is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread Thread-65:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File     "/home/swizec/Documents/trees/bookmarklet_server/../bookmarklet_server/Scrobbler/Scrobbler.py", line 60, in run
    scrobble_bookmark(self.account)
  File     "/home/swizec/Documents/trees/bookmarklet_server/../bookmarklet_server/Scrobbler/Scrobbler.py", line 28, in scrobble_bookmark
    bookmark = Bookmark.objects.all()[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 152, in __getitem__
    return list(qs)[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 76, in __len__
self._result_cache.extend(list(self._iter))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 231, in iterator
    for row in self.query.results_iter():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 281, in results_iter
    for rows in self.execute_sql(MULTI):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 2373, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 193, in execute
    return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)
OperationalError: no such table: Scrobbler_bookmark
```

PS: all other tests depending on the same table pass with flying colours.

Comment: "what I call a scrobbler".  Why is that in the question?  I can't see how it helps.

Comment: I guess it doesn't really, but it's there for completeness' sake.

Comment: Since you said: "what I call a Scrobbler" and I feel funny today I'll ask this way: dude why not you run python manage.py syncdb?

Answer (score 2):

You can not use threading with in memory databases (sqlite3 in this case) in Django see this [bug](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/12118). This might work with PostgreSQL or MySQL.

I'd recommend something like celeryd instead of threads, message queues are MUCH easier to work with than threading.

Comment: Be careful when posting copy and paste boilerplate/verbatim answers to multiple questions, these tend to be flagged as "spammy" by the community.

Comment: Sure ... but both questions had the same answer and, if you note, I actually gave two different answers.  And, of course, nobody upvoted these correct answers, including yourself.  The community is fickle if nothing else :-)

Answer (score 1):

This calls for a task queue, though not necessarily threads. You'll have your server process, one or several scrobbler processes, and a queue that lets them communicate. The queue can be in the database, or something separate like a beanstalkd. All this has nothing to do with your error, which sounds like your database is just misconfigured.

Comment: If the database is misconfigured, then how come all other tests based on the same table pass fine?

Comment: Yes. Celery + some MQ (or database table). Separate the concerns here. I think the OP is trying to square peg a round hole.

Answer (score 1):

1) Does the error persist if you use a real database, not SQLite?

2) If you're using threads, you might need to create separate SQL cursors for use in threads.

Answer (score 0):

i think the table really doesn't exists yew have to create it first by SQL commad 
or any other way. As i have a small database for testing different modules i just delete
the database and recreate it using syncdb command